# request works with Postman but not with axios.post

Tags: reactjs, post, request, axios, postman

I created a registration form in React-js with axios.post().
The request works perfectly via Postman which makes the backend guilt-free, 
but don't have any reaction in my component.

Using Try/catch or finally() don't have any effect.
i don't have any errors in the console.
All my variables are defined as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        passwd: ''
    }
}

onFieldChange(fieldName) {
    return function (event) {
        this.setState({[fieldName]: event.target.value});
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        [...]
        <form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit()}>
        <input type="password" value={this.state.passwd}
               onChange={this.onFieldChange('passwd').bind(this)} 
               placeholder="* Password" required />
            <button type="submit">Sign-up</button>
        </form>
        [...]
```

the problem part: 
(the (if/else) is working properly and redirection to /SignIn works elsewhere)

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    if (this.state.email === this.state.email02
        && this.state.passwd === this.state.passwd02
        && this.state.lastname !== '') {
        const data = {
            email: this.state.email,
            passwd: this.state.passwd,
            lastname: this.state.lastname,
            firstname: this.state.firstname
        }
        const config = {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }

        axios.post('http://104.XX.YY.192:8081/register', data, config)
            .then(response => {
                this.props.history.push('/SignIn');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    } else if (this.state.email !== this.state.email02) {
        console.log('email are not the same');
    } else if (this.state.passwd !== this.state.passwd02) {
        console.log('password are not the same');
    }
}
```

i'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: What error it is showing in the browser? or the url is connected but response is emoty?

Comment: there is no error at all actually. that's why i'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution by myself.
the 'form' tag reloads the page after sending the request.
Changing the form to div tags solves my problem.

Comment: For the sake of your semantic, you can still keep your form in your markup, but on the submit, call the method `event.preventDefault()` in order to prevent your form from reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given the proper Error Log so could not get the exact problem.Thus providing you one of my working code.It may help.
This code snippet is taking the url and then posting the data.Here you may come across CORS issue. If yes, then in package.json write -

> "proxy": "http://192.128.1.210:8080"

and install http-middleware-proxy. It will work fine:

```
export function PostData(userData) {
  var targetUrl = '/report' /* /register in your case.*/
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(targetUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "requestData": {
            "userName": userData.username,
            "password": userData.password,
            "clientId": "ptm",
            "txnType": "GDR"
          }
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        resolve(responseJson)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error)
      })
  })
```

With the axios one, this is one of the example you can try:

```
const user = {
  name: this.state.name
};

axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, {
    user
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
  })
}
```

Comment: Also, try to console your response you are getting to check whether the response is there or it is catching any error. Use console.log everywhere possible in case of any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Check your spaces, commas, quotation marks, especially spaces when setting headers, while in Postman you write it in the boxes but when you hardcoding in the code editor, sometimes you misspelled or put extra space vs and this may cause errors

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem apparently my login function accepted 2 strings but I was passing a json object of 2 strings I had to make some changes in the API controller

Created a Login class

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string pass { get; set; }
}
```

and made an object for UserLogin as a parameter so that it can accept userID and Password

```
 public String Post(UserLogin ul){}
```